# UITextField does not automatically resize width to fit contents until resignFirstResponder is called?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I'm not sure why this is happening, but basically I have a static cell, which consists of a `UITextField`. The `inputView` is a `UIPickerView` and its `inputAccessoryType` is a `UIToolBar`.

I created it like so:

```
var repeat_ARRAY: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    repeat_ARRAY.append("No Cycle")
    repeat_ARRAY.append("Semi-Monthly")

    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissPicker(_:) ) )

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    createCell()
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return repeat_ARRAY[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    textField.text = repeat_ARRAY[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return repeat_ARRAY.count
}

func dismissPicker(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func createCell()
{
    textField.text = "No Cycle"
    textField.delegate = self

    let pickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    textField.inputView = pickerView

    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

And this is how it is set up in storyboard:

[image]

When the ViewController is initially loaded, the `textField.text` value is **No Cycle**, which fits fine. However, when I scroll the `UIPickerView` to select the 2nd row, i.e. **Semi-Monthly**, the text gets cut-off like so:

[image]

It's not until I hit the **Done** `UIBarButtonItem` to call `textField.resignFirstResponder` that the width of the `textField` automatically exands to fit the contents of the string **Semi-Monthly** like so:
[image]

I don't quite understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Set 'leading, trailing, top and fixed height constraint' to your textfield and your issue will be solved ! If you can't set leading and trailing both then you should set fixed width.

Comment: But setting a fixed width will mean text field will not automatically adjust its width based on the contents of the text. I don't want the text field to take up a lot of width space if it does not need to. I thought that was the whole point of setting a width priority lower than the Horizontal `Hugging Priority`? I'm trying to achieve this with Auto-Layout in mind because I have `UILabel` on the left edge of the cell that can take up a lot of space also.

Comment: You can set minimum font scale or size also, so if text will be large string then it will reduce the font size to fit in label. If it is appropriate for you! Second thing in your current approach which you have posted in question call layoutifneeded or layoutsubviews in your didselectrow method of picker.

Comment: My requirement is to keep the font size the same, not scale it if the text is a large string. As mentioned, I thought this was taken care of with the `Hugging Priority`.

Comment: Hi @Pangu were you able to figure this out?